# Dockerization of Python App not showing anything

Tags: python, docker

I have a python app with

**my-python-app**

- static (contains css, images)
- templates

  - results.html
  - upload.html
- utils

  - someutilfiles.py
- main.py
- requirements.txt
- Dockerfile

This is a web app running on port 5000. I tested running it on my local as a python project and it is working fine. When I tried to dockerize it, it does not seem to be running. I tried accessing the logs but nothing is being shown.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./main.py
```

I am building and running it using

```
docker build -t my-python-app .
docker run -p 5000:5000 my-python-app
```

docker container is running but no logs and localhost:5000 is just not reachable

Can someone let me know what I am missing here, in the source code or docker config?

**UPDATE**

**main.py**

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    from utils.GraphGenerator import 
 

createSpecificCapacityWithEfficiencyGraph,createSingleCycleChargeDischargeGraph, createDifferentialCapacityGraph, createDischargeCycleWithCapacity
from flask import send_file
from uuid import uuid1
import pandas as pd
from utils.FileIOUtils import dataDict
import gc
import os
import time
from flask import send_from_directory, current_app, redirect, url_for
import zipfile
app = Flask(__name__)
# folderPath = "/tmp/"
folderPath = "./static/results/"
@app.route('/upload')
def main():
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve

    serve(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
    app.run()
```

**requirements.txt**

```
certifi==2021.10.8
click==8.0.3
cycler==0.11.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
Flask==2.0.2
fonttools==4.28.3
importlib-metadata==4.8.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
joblib==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.3.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.5.1
numpy==1.21.4
openpyxl==3.0.9
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.3.4
Pillow==8.4.0
pyparsing==3.0.6
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.0.1
waitress==2.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.2
xlrd==2.0.1
zipp==3.6.0
```

Comment: What's your `docker ps` output! If you start your app with a simple print, is it shown?

Comment: docker ps shows the app is running. yes, simple print works. it exits the container immediately though, which is to be expected.

Comment: Then the problem lies within the code.

Comment: I initially thought of the same. But the code runs well

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting using `docker container logs CONTAINER_ID`?

Comment: Also, what are you expecting to get from visiting localhost:5000? are you running a web server or something?

Comment: *"But the code runs well"* Well, you can close the question then.

Comment: I agree that the Dockerfile and `docker run` command seem fine; can you edit the question to include a minimal runnable subset of the application code as well?  (There's at least one common setup problem with Flask applications, but I have no idea if you're using that.)